# Laravel 4 equolent - how do I change default DB dynamically?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following configuration in database.php:

```
 'connections' => array(

    'sqlite' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),

    'mysql-primary' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host1',
        'port'      => '3306',
        'database'  => 'test',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

     'mysql-slave' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host2',
        'port'      => '3306',
        'database'  => 'test',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    'default' => 'mysql-primary',
)
```

What I would like to achieve is switching from primary DB to slave DB in case of unavailability. Lets say user tries to login:

```
$user = User::where('username', '=', $username)->first();
```

I want here, if there is PDOException (which is supposed to be thrown in case of unavailability) to switch the default database and retry the operation. I know its possible in the User model, but I want to switch in all models.

What I have tried with no success:

```
App::error(function(PDOException $exception) 
{
    Log::error("Error connecting to database: ".$exception->getMessage());
    DB::setDefaultConnection('mysql-slave');
});
```

in filters.php

```
 'default' => getDatabase()


function getDatabase() 
{
   try{
     DB::connection('mysql-master')->getDatabaseName();
   }catch(PDOException $e){
     return 'mysql-slave';
   }
  return 'mysql-master';
}
```

in database.php

Both not working. Is there any way for such behaviour in Laravel 4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that: you can't do this using the facades (DB:: etc).

Why?  The facades use an internal singleton instance that is initialised at the time that the facade is first accessed.  If you dig deep into the Laravel code you will find, in the bootstrap / register functions of the service providers including the DB service provider that there is an internal DB object created as a singleton.  This object is of class Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory and has a pre-initialised internal PDO object that is created from the configuration that's stored in the config variables.

The longer answer is that you can create one or more your own objects of class Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory using code that's similar to the bootstrap code in the database service provider.  I suggest that you have a good read through that bootstrap code and become familiar with it and the code and its documentation can be found here: https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseServiceProvider.html

There is probably another work-around for this which includes providing extra connectors of type Illuminate\Database\Connection (all of which can be set up in the config as you have done) to the ConnectionFactory.  That would involve extending the existing ConnectionFactory class, and changing the DB service provider to use your own extension rather than the Laravel native class.  You could then have the ConnectionFactory providing a connection that had failover built in.  It's fairly complex but possible -- I have done it for the ViewFactory class but never for the ConnectionFactory class.

I'm sorry that this isn't a simple HOWTO to answer your question but it gives you an idea of why this doesn't work simply with the examples that you have given.  It's probably simpler to do using a MySQL proxy or load balancing service, for example, that automatically detected which server was running and sent requests to that.